# Python sum of the array elements

Tags: python, arrays, file

I have file with following lines:

```
date:ip num#1 num#2   

2013.09:142.134.35.17 10 12
2013.09:142.134.35.17 4 4
2013.09:63.151.172.31 52 13
2013.09:63.151.172.31 10 10
2013.09:63.151.172.31 16 32
2013.10:62.151.172.31 16 32
```

How do I sum up the last two elements with the same IP to get such a conclusion?

```
2013.09:142.134.35.17 14 16
2013.09:63.151.172.31 78 55
2013.10:62.151.172.31 16 32
```

Comment: Q: What have you tried?

Comment: I've already done:
file = open("full_megalog.txt", "r")
     for line in  file:

Comment: @JohnSmith This doesn't count as trying ;\

Comment: Are you sure you want to sum up elements with only the same IP, or do they also need to occur on the same date, i.e., have the same `date:ip` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('full_megalog.txt') as f:
    data = [d.split() for d in f]

sum1, sum2 = Counter(), Counter()

for d in data:
    sum1[d[0]] += int(d[1])
    sum2[d[0]] += int(d[2])

for date_ip in sum1.keys():
    print date_ip, sum1[date_ip], sum2[date_ip]
```

Comment: Why a `Counter` and why not a `defaultdict(int)`? This is not a good use case for `Counter`

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with your statement, this is a very good use case for `Counter`.

Comment: It'd be constructive to hear the why from both sides of the discussion.

Comment: @TankorSmash I have given an explanation already: a simple, working solution which is rather self-explanatory.

Comment: @1_CR -- A `Counter` works a lot like `defaultdict(int)` except that it has a bunch of other useful methods that you can use later... I think this is a find use for `Counter`, although it definitely doesn't showcase all of the neat things counters can do :)

Comment: ok @mgilson and everyone, comment withdrawn :-)

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.
But I'm sorry I got so many disadvantages: (

Comment: I don't understand people downvoting such posts. You have asked a clear question and provided nice sample data and expected output, that's perfect, afaik. You'll get few points if you mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @JohnSmith The reason is stated clearly in the question's close reason. The purpose of this site is not people doing other people's job for them.

Comment: @BartoszKP, Sorry, I did not know. I thought that people here can help me, but I was wrong.

Comment: @JohnSmith I think you've misunderstood my comment. People here can, and will help you. This has nothing to do with closing and downvoting questions that lack some minimal effort from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
addrs='''\
2013.09:142.134.35.17 10 12
2013.09:142.134.35.17 4 4
2013.09:63.151.172.31 52 13
2013.09:63.151.172.31 10 10
2013.09:63.151.172.31 16 32
2013.10:62.151.172.31 16 32'''

class Dicto(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key]=[0,0]
        return self[key]

r=Dicto()
for line in addrs.splitlines():
    ip,n1,n2=line.split()
    r[ip][0]+=int(n1)
    r[ip][1]+=int(n2)

print r   
# {'2013.09:142.134.35.17': [14, 16], 
   '2013.09:63.151.172.31': [78, 55], 
   '2013.10:62.151.172.31': [16, 32]}
```

Or, if you prefer, with defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
r=defaultdict(lambda: [0,0])
for line in addrs.splitlines():
    ip,n1,n2=line.split()
    r[ip][0]+=int(n1)
    r[ip][1]+=int(n2)

print r
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited @piokuc's answer since he asked for the ip specifically, not the date+ip.
The split and summing is done on the ip only.

```
from collections import Counter
import re
data=\
"""2012.09:142.134.35.17 10 12
2013.09:142.134.35.17 4 4
2013.09:63.151.172.31 52 13
2013.09:63.151.172.31 10 10
2013.09:63.151.172.31 16 32
2013.10:62.151.172.31 16 32"""


data = [re.split('[: ]',d) for d in data.split('\n')]
print data
sum1 = Counter()
sum2 = Counter()
for d in data:
    sum1[d[1]] += int(d[2])
    sum2[d[1]] += int(d[3])

for date_ip in sum1.keys():
    print date_ip, sum1[date_ip], sum2[date_ip]
```

Answer (score 1):

@piokuc's answer is very good; here's a naive solution that should be easy for a beginner to understand, without having to reach into the standard library for `Counter`.

The result you're looking for is structured as a set of two (ordered) values, each associated with a unique label (the `date:ip` value). In Python the basic data structure for this sort of task is a `dict` (dictionary).

It's good practice when you open files to make sure you close them when they're no longer needed. I'll use the `with` statement for this; if you're interested in more details about how it works, [this is a good resource](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), but if that's over your head just remember that once the `with` block ends, the file you are working *with* will be closed automatically.

Here's the code - and remember that everything you read from a file will be as characters, which means you have to convert numbers appropriately before performing any sort of math on them:

```
result = {}                                        # Create your empty dict

with open('full_megalog.txt', 'r') as file:        # Open your input file

    for line in file:                              # In each line of the file:

        date_ip, num1, num2 = line.split()         # 1:  Get key and 2 values

        if date_ip in result:                      # 2:  Check if key exists

            result[date_ip][0] += int(num1)        # 3a: If yes, add num1, num2
            result[date_ip][1] += int(num2)        #     to current sum.

        else:                                      # 3b: If no, add the new key
            result[date_ip] = int(num1), int(num2) #     and values to the dict
```

Now you have a `result` dictionary which associates the sums of `num1` and `num2` with each corresponding `date_ip`. You can access the `(num1, num2)` tuple with `result[date_ip]`, and you can access the values individually with `result[date_ip][0]` and `result[date_ip][1]`.

If you want to write this in the original format, you'll have to join each key and two values together with a space character; the long-winded, easily-commented way to do this might be something like:

```
with open('condensed_log_file.txt', 'w') as out:       # open the output file;

    for date_ip in result:                             # loop through the keys;

        out.write(                                     # write to the logfile:

                  ' '.join(                            # joined by a space char,
                           (date_ip,                   # the key (date_ip);
                            str(result[date_ip][0]),   # the 1st value (num1);
                            str(result[date_ip][1]))   # & the 2nd value (num2).
                          )
```

I was curious to see how the performance compared between piokuc's very neat and clean method, and my own naive method. This is without the printing and outfile writing statements:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> a = open("airthomas.py", "r")
>>> a = a.read()
>>> p = open("piokuc.py", "r")
>>> p = p.read()
>>> timeit(p)
115.33428788593137
>>> timeit(a)
103.95908962552267
```

So, if you need to run this on a great number of small files, using `Counter()` may be just a little bit slower. Of course, you probably need to run it on just one or a handful of very large files - in which case, do your own testing! ;P

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a dictionary to help you with your problem, like this:**

```
#assuming that your addresses are stored in a file:
with open('addresses.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    ele = {}

    for line in lines:
        addr = line.split()
        s = [int(addr[1]), int(addr[2])]
        if addr[0] in ele:
            ele[addr[0]][0] += s[0]
            ele[addr[0]][1] += s[1]
        else:
            ele[addr[0]] = s
```

This gives you:

```
{'2013.09:142.134.35.17': [14, 16],
 '2013.09:63.151.172.31': [78, 55],
 '2013.10:62.151.172.31': [16, 32]}
```